# how can merge one array values in one integer c++

Tags: c++, avr, atmega16

How can i merge one array values in one integer and upside down?

```
example: a[]=0b1011,0b1111 to 10111111 and 10010101 to b[]=0b1001,0b0101
```

Comment: What is `a` and `b` *really* supposed to be? Because you can't have four-bit integers (unless you're on some very odd or old system).

Comment: And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `upside down?` like this: "*1010q0'1001q0=[]q oʇ 10101001 puɐ 11111101 oʇ 1111q0'1101q0=[]ɐ :ǝʃdɯɐxǝ*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to covert types so that the values so they can hold 8 bits (a char or uint8 would do depending on what you need). I'm not sure what type you have there as its 4 bits. You're better off redefining the type to be a uint8 or something so a[0] = 0b00001011.

Once you have the right number of bits need to bitshift the first value left by 4, then use the bitwise OR operator, taking your example,

```
int8 myValue = a[0] << 4 | a[1]
```

Here's whats going on

- Bitshift: a[0] << 4 means move every bit to the left 4 times so 0b00001011 becomes 0b10110000 (bits coming into the right default as 0)
- Bitwise OR: a[0] << 4 | a[1], the | compares every bit from a[0] with a[1]. If either on of the bits are 1's it gives a 1, if both are 0, it gives a 0 i.e.

  10110000 | 00001111 = **10111111**

By upside down I assume you mean in reverse?

You'll need to use the bitwise AND &, and do something similar so I wont explain in detail again, but its this

```
a[0] = (myValue & 0b1111000) >> 4 = 00001011

a[1] = myValue & 0b00001111 = 00001111
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` and `|` to "paste" two integers together, `>>` and `&` to take them apart.

For instance, `(3 << 4) | 5` is 53, `53 >> 4` is 3, `53 & 7` is 5.
(Translating the integers to binary notation left as an exercise.)

Answer (score 0):

tnq for help,i want a code to do this

```
a[]={1,2,3,5,8,6,7,4};
result=a[0,1,2,3]+a[4,5,6,7];
result-->9909
```